# Help resolving SQL error that occurs in code but not in SQL workbench

Tags: php, sql

I run this command in SQL Workbench and it returns my desired results, but it return a syntax error in the browser...

```
$sql = "SELECT
        SUBSTRING(`last_name`, 1, 1) AS alpha,
        SUBSTRING(`middle_name`, 1, 1) AS subMiddleName,
        `idClients`,
        `type`,
        `first_name`,
        `middle_name`,
        `last_name`,
        `address`,
        `primary_number`,
        `secondary_number`,
        `home_number`,
        `office_number`,
        `cell_number`,
        `fax_number`,
        `ext_number`,
        `other_number`,
        `comments`
    FROM `clients`
    WHERE `user_id` = 2
    AND `is_sub` = 0
    AND `prospect` = 1
    ORDER BY `last_name`";
```

Also `user_id`, `is_sub`, and `prospect` are of the INT data type if anyone wants to know. I tried to treat them as strings in the query, but that still didn't help.

this is the error i get

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND `prospect` = 1 AND `type` = 'Buyer'' at line 1

Comment: Given the error, this isn't the query that you're running, since you don't have a condition for `type='Buyer'` in the pasted query but do in the error.

Comment: Are those backticks (`) surrounding the column names and table name?  Did you try the query with regular single-quotes (')?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not showing us the same query, or the relevant PHP code, as nowhere does the above query use the string `'Buyer'`.

That said, you may need to escape the column name `type` with backticks:

```
AND `prospect` = 1 AND `type` = 'Buyer'
```

Comment: You are correct, I was under the assumption that that block of code was in error and completely forgot I had another query running before this query was executed. My apologies